# How to get a value inside an ArrayList java

Tags: java

I am trying to get a value from with in an ArrayList. Here is a sample of my code:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    Car toyota= new Car("Toyota", "$10000", "300"+ "2003");
    Car nissan= new Car("Nissan", "$22000", "300"+ "2011");
    Car ford= new Car("Ford", "$15000", "350"+ "2010");

    ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    cars.add(toyota);        
    cars.add(nissan);
    cars.add(ford);
}

public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){

   // in heare i need a way of getting the total cost of all three cars by calling 
    //  computeCars ()
    System.out.println(cars.get());
}
```

revision
thanks all for the answers, I should probably add to the code a bit more. in the Car class, i have another method that is calculating the total cost including the tax.

```
class Car {
    public Car (String name, int price, int, tax, int year){
        constructor.......
    }

    public void computeCars (){
        int  totalprice= price+tax;
        System.out.println (name + "\t" +totalprice+"\t"+year );
     } 
}
```

in the main class

```
public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){
    int totalAmount=0;
    for (int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){
        cars.get(i).computeCars ();
        totalAmount=+ ?? // in need to add the computed values of totalprice from the  Car class?
    }
}
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming your `Car` class has a getter method for price, you can simply use

```
System.out.println (car.get(i).getPrice());
```

where `i` is the index of the element.

You can also use

```
Car c = car.get(i);
System.out.println (c.getPrice());
```

You also need to return `totalprice` from your function if you need to store it

**main**

```
public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){
    int totalAmount=0;
    for (int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){
        int totalprice= cars.get(i).computeCars ();
        totalAmount=+ totalprice; 
    }
}
```

And change the `return` type of your function

```
public int computeCars (){
    int  totalprice= price+tax;
    System.out.println (name + "\t" +totalprice+"\t"+year );
    return  totalprice; 
 }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, I tried that but it is saying it is expecting an int but found void. I am not sure how to get around that. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You haven't shown your `Car` type, but assuming you'd want the price of the first car, you could use:

```
public static void processCars(ArrayList<Car> cars) {
    Car car = cars.get(0);
    System.out.println(car.getPrice());
}
```

Note that I've changed the name of the list from `car` to `cars` - this is a *list* of cars, not a *single* car. (I've changed the method name in a similar way.)

If you only want the method to process a *single* car, you should change the parameter to be of type `Car`:

```
public static void processCar(Car car)
```

and then call it like this:

```
// In the main method
processCar(cars.get(0));
```

If you *do* leave it as processing the whole list, it would be worth generalizing the parameter to `List<Car>` - it's unlikely that you'll really require that it's an `ArrayList<Car>`.

Comment: Type in the ArrayList should be Car, not Cars ;-)

Comment: @stiank81: I think you meant that comment to addressed to home's answer, not mine...

Comment: Actually you had it wrong in yours too, but Petar edited it.. No big deal though..

Answer (score 2):

***main class***

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Car thisCar= new Car ("Toyota", "$10000", "2003");  
        ArrayList<Car> car= new ArrayList<Car> ();
        car.add(thisCar); 
        processCar(car);
    } 

    public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> car){
        for(Car c : car){
            System.out.println (c.getPrice());
        }
    }
}
```

***car class***

```
public class Car {
    private String vehicle;
    private String price;
    private String model;

    public Car(String vehicle, String price, String model){
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
        this.model = model;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getVehicle() {
        return vehicle;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should name your list `cars` instead of `car`, so that its name matches its content.

Then you can simply say `cars.get(0).getPrice()`. And if your `Car` class doesn't have this method yet, you need to create it.

Answer (score 0):

The list may contain several elements, so the get method takes an argument : the index of the element you want to retrieve. If you want the first one, then it's 0.

The list contains Car instances, so you just have to do

```
Car firstCar = car.get(0);
String price = firstCar.getPrice();
```

or just

```
String price = car.get(0).getPrice();
```

The `car` variable should be named `cars`, since it's a list and thus contains several cars.

Read the [tutorial about collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/). And learn to use the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/): all the classes and methods are documented.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the price of all cars you have to iterate through the array list:

```
public static void processCars(ArrayList<Cars> cars) {
   for (Car c : cars) {
       System.out.println (c.getPrice());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class hari
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{  Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=0;
    int b=0;
    HashSet<Integer> h=new HashSet<Integer>();
    try{
        for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {   b=s.nextInt();
        h.add(b);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(h+","+h.size());
    }
}}
```

Comment: This solution perfectly suits ur question ... I hope