# how to store a array of String in Array List. can we use array of an Array List. if yes then how?

Tags: java

is it possible to run the following code with logic in 6th line ?

```
public class arraylist{
    public static void main(String args{}){
        String s[]={"Sam","Tom","Jerry"};
        ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
        al.add(s);//i want this type of logic so i can add the elements of string once.is it possible?
    }

    Iterator it=al1.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {

        String element=String.valueOf(it.next());
        System.out.print("Element"+element);
    }
}
```

Comment: _is it possible to execute the following code_ Do you have Java installed on your computer?

Comment: Try executing it on Java and tell us the result.

Comment: Also, not an answer to your question but using arraylists like that is unwise, you should use generics, eg ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>()

Comment: There is an `asList()` method in the Arrays class. `Arrays.asList(s)`;

Comment: I think there may be some misunderstanding here, by "is it possible to execute the following code." do you mean; will this code run? If you mean; I'd like this code to run and it doesn't; then explain how it fails to run

Comment: `public static void main(String args{})` is not valid.

Comment: Other comments; I think you typoed a `{}` instead of a `[]` in your `public static void main(String args{})` and the iterator and while loop are just hanging around not inside a method which I suspect java doesn't like. Also its convention for class names to start with capital letters so `Arraylist` not `arraylist` and its an insanely bad idea to call you class the same name as a built in class so actually call it `MyClass` instead of `arraylist`

Answer (score 7):

Change `al.add(s);`  by `al.addAll(Arrays.asList(s));`  and you should be all set.

Comment: I think you want addall

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s));
```

Comment: oh thanku sir...and could you please tell me how can i exctract the data from this class ?

Comment: and please tell me how data is will be save in this arraylist class

Comment: @user2281498 use arrayList.get(index) to get things back out. Try seeing what methods the arraylist has, its usually self evident

Comment: @user2281498 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950884/how-to-get-a-value-inside-an-arraylist-java

Comment: Well, I like the `Sir` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your question.

When you say you want to convert array [asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Answer (score 0):

`al.add(s);//i want this type of logic so i can add the elements of string once.is it possible ?`
Yes. It is possible.You can add any object to `ArrayList` including array object.
But while iterating the `ArrayList` object you will get an array element by calling `it.next()`.So output will be `String representation of array object` not the array elements
So try this

```
String s[]={"Sam","Tom","Jerry"};
ArrayList<String> al=Arrays.asList(s);        
Iterator it=al.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    String element=String.valueOf(it.next());
    System.out.print("Element"+element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As many have already suggested, use Arrays.asList.  But before the code would work, you would still need to fix the formatting as you have code outside the main method that is referring to your array list variable in the main method.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    String s[]={"Sam","Tom","Jerry"};
    ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
    al.add(Arrays.asList(s));

    Iterator it=al.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {

        String element=String.valueOf(it.next());
        System.out.print("Element"+element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to store arrays in a ArrayList. The declaration is:

```
ArrayList<String[]> training = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

To input the words and add it:

```
String input = sc.nextLine();
s1 = input.split(" ");
training.add(s1);
```

The split method splits the string with spaces and stores each word in the respective index in array s1 which was already declared with the size required for the program."sc" is the scanner object already declared.The individual arrays can be accessed by using:

```
String s4[] = training.get(index_of_array_you_want);
```

Answer (score 0):

Element[] array = {new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3)};

ArrayList arr=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array))