# Android How to display Values from array in the Textview

Tags: android, arraylist, textview

[923332099903,24975924,923332122440,57375]

I am getting the above values in the ArrayList,now i want to display the values in the textview or radiobutton like the following example:

923332099903

923332122440

My Activity is:

```
private ArrayList<String> AssociatedArray = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> AssociatedArrayIndexes = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
     setContentView(R.layout.change_number);
     getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

     AssociatedArray = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("AssociatedArray"); 


}
```

Comment: In ListView or, if `AssociatedArray` has small size, you have to generete TextViews/Radios from code (inside some ScrollView) ... both solutions are well described over the internet ... and your question do not shows any efforts on your side ...

Comment: here is showing how to get value from ArrayList  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950884/how-to-get-a-value-inside-an-arraylist-java  and here how to set text in TextView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300169/how-to-change-text-in-android-textview

Answer (score 0):

Create your own list view with customised view(i.e it contains radio button) and pass your array list to your adapter.